# Does disabling anonymous access in IIS create a security risk?

Tags: windows, security, http, iis

If I *uncheck* the "Enable anonymous access" checkbox in IIS, so as to password protect a site, i.e. by restricting read access to designated Windows accounts, does the resulting password dialogue which is then presented to all anonymous http requests, represent a security risk in that it (seemingly) offers all and sundry an unlimited number of attempts to guess at any Windows account password?

EDIT:
Okay, not much joy with this so far, so I'm attaching a bounty. Just 50 points sorry, I am a man of modest means. To clarify what I'm after: does disabling anonymous access in IIS offer a password guessing opportunity to the public which did not exist previously, or is it the case that the browser's user credentials dialogue can be simulated by including a username and password in a http request directly, and that the response would indicate whether the combination was correct even though the page was open to anonymous users anyway? Furthermore, are incorrect password attempts submitted via http subject to the same lockout policy enforced for internal logins, and if so does this represent a very easy opportunity to deliberately lock out known usernames, or alternatively, if not, is there anything that can be done to mitigate this unlimited password guessing opportunity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose an authentication other than Anonymous, you certainly can be subject to password hacking.  However, the account that is uses is subject to the standard account lockout policies set in Local Security Policy and your Domain's security policy.

For example, if you have a local account "FRED" and the account lockout policy is set to 5 invalid attempts within 30 minutes, then this effectively prevents account password guessing, at the risk of a denial of service attack.  However, setting the reset window to a value (15 minutes?) effectively limits the DOS.

- Basic Authentication is not recommeded for a non-SSL connection since the password will travel in plain text.
- Digest Authentication requires passwords to be stored on the server using a reversible encryption, so while better than Basic, Digest has its flaws.
- Windows Integrated Authentication
  includes NTLM and Kerberos.

  - The IIS Server should be configured via Group Policy or Local Security settings to disable LM authentication ( Network security: LAN Manager authentication level set to "Send NTLMv2 response only" or higher, preferred is "Send NTLMv2 response only\refuse LM & NTLM") to prevent trivial LM hash cracking and to prevent NTLM man in the middle proxy attacks.
  - Kerberos can be used, however it only works if both machines are members of the same domain and the DC's can be reached.  Since this doesn't typically happen over the internet, you can ignore Kerberos.

So the end result is, yes, disabling anonymous does open you up for password cracking attempts and DOS attacks, but these can be prevented and mitigated.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just to clarify, is it the case that such a password guessing opportunity does not exist when Anonymous authentication is in place, i.e. by sending directly whatever request headers the password dialogue sends, and still receiving some kind of informative response?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is yes. Any time you give any remote access to any resource on your network it presents a security risk. Your best bet would be to follow [IIS best practices](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596cdf5a-c852-4b79-b55a-708e5283ced5.mspx?mfr=true) and then take some precautions of your own. [Rename your built in administrator account](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Protecting-Administrator-Account.html). Enforce strong password policies. [Change the server header](http://windowsitpro.com/Web/article/articleid/22967/changing-the-server-http-header.html). Removing anonymous access, while a password guessing risk, is a very manageable one if used with the proper layered security model.

Answer (score 2):

You should read about differnet authentication mechanisms available: Basic, Digest, NTLM, Certificates, etc. The IETF [compiled a document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-security-properties-03) that dicusses the pros and cons of some of these (NTLM is propriatary MS protocol).

Bottom line is: You are not done with just disabling anonymous access. You definitely have to consider carefully what the attack scenarios are, what the potential damage might be, what user may be willing to accept and so on.

If you introduce authorization you need to address the risk of credentials being compromised. You should also think if what you actually want to achieve is confidential transport of the content: In this case you will have to instroduce transport layer security like SSL.

Answer (score 1):

I am by know means a hosting guru and I imagine there are ways and means of doing this but my personal opinion is that what you are talking about doing is defiantly an unnecessary security risk. If this site is to be available on the internet i.e. it will have public access then you probably don't want to disable anonymous access in IIS.

Please remember that the idea of being able to configure the anonymous access for a site in IIS is so that you can create a user which has specific permission to read the relevant files for a particular site. What we are talking about here is file access on a physical disc. For one thing a public web server should be in a DMZ and not part of your companies domain so users should not be able to log in with their domain credentials anyway.

The only reason why I could imagine that you would want to switch off anonymous access and force users to input their Windows credentials is for a site which will only be used internally and even then I would probably not choose to restrict access in this manner.

If you want to restrict access to content on a public website then you would probably be better of writing something which handles authentication as part of the site itself or a service which the site can consume. Then if someone were to obtain user credentials then at least all they will be able to do is gain access to the site and there is no potential for a breach of your internal network by any means.

There is a reason why developers spend allot of time writing user management solutions. You will find plenty of advice on how to write something like this and plenty of libraries that will do most of the work for you.